# Why does system.float not exist in .net?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, types

Why does .Net not have the `System.Float` type like `System.String`, `System.Double` etc.?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It has type `System.Single`, which is what you are looking for.

See [table for built-in value types in C# at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds).

There is a slight discrepancy between how types are called in C# (where name-type are similar to C-languages, but not the same (for example - `long` type)) and in .Net Framework, which should be language independent of course, as many languages can (and do) run on it.

Answer (score 8):

Because it is an alias of `System.Single`

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx

Answer (score 8):

It's like `int` is `System.Int32`, `float` is `System.Single`